# MOXy compatible XML and JSON responses

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, moxy

I have a POJO with JAXB annotations, it works well marshalling to xml and json, however, the xml and json are not compatible since the root tag is lost in json. I know it makes more sense in json but I still need the root element. Is there a way to get it?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = XmlConsts.ELEMENT)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Element {
    private static final String MULTIPLE_VALUE_DELIMITER = ",";

    @XmlElement(name = XmlConsts.PROPERTIES)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JaxbMapAdapter.class)
    private final Map<String, String> entries;

    @XmlAttribute(name = XmlConsts.ELEMENT_TYPE, required = false)
    public String getType() {
        return entries.get(XmlConsts.ELEMENT_TYPE);
    }
    ...
```

Result xml:

```
<element type="rule.record">
  <properties>
    <property name="min" value="0"/>
    <property name="id" value="1773"/>
...
```

Result json:

```
{"type":"rule.record","properties":{
"property":[
{"name":"min","value":"0"},
{"name":"id","value":"1773"}
```

As seen here, the 'element' tag is lost in the json. Is there a way to get the root element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are a few ways this can be done based on the environment that you are running in:

### Standalone Example

When using the standard JAXB APIs MOXy will include the root element when marshalling to JSON.  This behaviour can be changed using the `JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT` property.  If it has been set to `false` when creating the `JAXBContext`, you can set it back to `true` on the `Marshaller`.

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello World");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

### JAX-RS and `MOXyJsonProvider`

MOXy includes an implementation of `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` which makes it easy to configure MOXy as your JSON-binding provider.  By default `MOXyJsonProvider` is configured not to include the root element.  You can change this by setting a configured instance on a JAX-RS `Application` class like the one below.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class FooApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(1);
        set.add(ExampleService.class);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();
        moxyJsonProvider.setIncludeRoot(true);

        HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(1);
        set.add(moxyJsonProvider);
        return set;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

### MOXy as the Default JSON-Binding Provider in Jersey/GlassFish

If you are using MOXy as the default JSON-binding provider with Jersey/GlassFish you can leverage the `MoxyJsonConfig` class as follows:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonConfig;

@Provider
public class MOXyJsonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {

    private final MoxyJsonConfig config;

    public MOXyJsonContextResolver() {
        config = new MoxyJsonConfig()
            .setIncludeRoot(true);
    }

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return config;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxy-is-new-default-json-binding.html